# init firebase from flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to initialize
Firebase from flutter main, without google-service-json, following the documentation I get the following error

```
PlatformException(firebase_core, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process nameproject.firebase
```

the way I do the initialization is as follows

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  name: 'xxxxxx', options: FirebaseOptions(
  appId: 'xxxxxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxx',
  apiKey: 'xxxxx',
  projectId: 'xxxxxx',
  databaseURL: 'xxxxx'))
  .then((value) {
print('goods');}).catchError((e) {
print('error');
print(e);});
```

I was guided by the documentation of a blog:

[blog multiple-firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)

Comment: The article is from 2016, could be outdated.

Comment: yes but it also in the official firebase documentation

[documentation firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects?fbclid=IwAR3gQ_bepE0ojtoc3PUShRr_Sn1Xwd0SPfsFds0fK9GUkbHRlx_RBQVabvw#kotlin+ktx) in klotin but I wanted to know if someone could do it in flutter

Comment: You can check the docs here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/